# Why only the first index of my vector is filled ?

Tags: c++

I am trying to store into a buffer the return value of the `recv` system call.

```
  std::vector<unsigned char *> tmpBuffer(BUFF_SIZE);
  unsigned int ret = ::recv(_sock, tmpBuffer.data(), tmpBuffer.size(), 0);
```

But when I look up into the content of tmpBuffer, only the first index(0) is filled with a data, and `ret` is superior to 1.

As a vector is continuous in memory, why isn't it filled ?

Comment: Remove the C tag, this is only C++

Comment: You are using pointer inside a vector. That means that `tmpBuffer.data()` is a pointer. Try: `std::vector<unsigned char> tmpBuffer(BUFF_SIZE);`. Allocate enough bytes and try again

Comment: `std::vector<unsigned char *>` remove the star.

Comment: I just would like to point out, that in this case, it would be more effective to use `std::array` than `std::vector`

Comment: @holmicz that depends on what `BUFF_SIZE` is. Large buffers should not be put on the stack.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I agree, good point, I just though that such message buffers are usually rather small